# Is number of lines on terminal is a limitation in IntelliJ community edition?

Tags: intellij-idea

On terminal, Intellij is limiting the output and i don't have option under settings to override console cycle buffer option. Is that a limitation on community edition?

Comment: AFAIK there is a limit on both editions (as their should be; there's only so many lines you care about in an app before you need it to be logged to an actual file).  How much output are you generating?

Comment: unfortunately, a lot of logs data on server startup. It is difficult to track errors without console output limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition has exactly the same setting to override the cycle buffer size as in Ultimate:

[image: buffer size]

This screenshot is from:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2
Build #IC-171.4249.39, built on April 25, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-855-b1 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```